# What configuration settings are required to use Hibernate with Postgres?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

What is the configuration for hibernate to connect to postgresql?

### code is

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class StudentHibernate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config .setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you google for "PostgreSQL driver class"? Does the world explode?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/load.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
config .setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"," org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one:

```
hibernate.connection.username=user
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url=url
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: I think you missed out on the part explaining that in this case he should use a `hibernate.properties` file.

Comment: the question was: what is the configuration, the configuration is there, it just needs to use the keys / values, they will be the same isn't it?